# What is the crc32 polynomial?

Tags: documentation, zip

What is the polynomial used for crc32? The ANSI X3.66 CRC-32 is 0x104C11DB7. The man page for crc32 does not indicate the polynomial it uses.

Comment: Can you clarify how this is about Ubuntu? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, this is an application included in the  libarchive-zip-perl package. There is a man page on "crc32". The man page does not indicate the polynomial that it uses to calculate the CRC-32. It also does not indicate the Endean-ness of the bytes as they are read from a file.

Comment: Sorry, but even though the `crc32` program is included in Ubuntu, I don't believe that the mathematical background of the standardized CRC32 algorithm is on topic on AskUbuntu.

Comment: The math, no, this is well documented in numerous college text books. The polynomial, yes. There are multiple polynomials that are associated with a 32-bit CRC calculation. The polynomial identifies the specific polynomial used in the calculation which is essential to verify the utilities results.

Answer (score 6):

The question as is phrased is off-topic, however I'll try to make it on-topic by addressing how to search for documentation on tools that rely on Perl modules in a general way; in order:

1. `man <tool>`;

   From `man crc32`:

   ```
          This utility is supplied with the Archive::Zip module for Perl.
   ```
2. `perldoc <module>`;

   From `perldoc Archive::Zip`:

   ```
       Archive::Zip::computeCRC32( $string [, $crc] )
       Archive::Zip::computeCRC32( { string => $string [, checksum => $crc ] } )
           This is a utility function that uses the Compress::Raw::Zlib CRC
           routine to compute a CRC-32.
   ```

   Apply recursively until something avails or the "root" module is reached; in this case the recursion ends with `perldoc Compress::Raw::Zlib`, which doesn't avail;
3. Dig the [source code of the "root" module](http://search.cpan.org/~pmqs/Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.069/lib/Compress/Raw/Zlib.pm):

   > Generate tables for a byte-wise 32-bit CRC calculation on the polynomial:
   >   x^32+x^26+x^23+x^22+x^16+x^12+x^11+x^10+x^8+x^7+x^5+x^4+x^2+x+1.
   >
   > Polynomials over GF(2) are represented in binary, one bit per coefficient,
   >   with the lowest powers in the most significant bit.  Then adding polynomials
   >   is just exclusive-or, and multiplying a polynomial by x is a right shift by
   >   one.  If we call the above polynomial p, and represent a byte as the
   >   polynomial q, also with the lowest power in the most significant bit (so the
   >   byte 0xb1 is the polynomial x^7+x^3+x+1), then the CRC is (q*x^32) mod p,
   >   where a mod b means the remainder after dividing a by b.
   >
   > This calculation is done using the shift-register method of multiplying and
   >   taking the remainder.  The register is initialized to zero, and for each
   >   incoming bit, x^32 is added mod p to the register if the bit is a one (where
   >   x^32 mod p is p+x^32 = x^26+...+1), and the register is multiplied mod p by
   >   x (which is shifting right by one and adding x^32 mod p if the bit shifted
   >   out is a one).  We start with the highest power (least significant bit) of
   >   q and repeat for all eight bits of q.
   >
   > The first table is simply the CRC of all possible eight bit values.  This is
   >   all the information needed to generate CRCs on data a byte at a time for all
   >   combinations of CRC register values and incoming bytes.  The remaining tables
   >   allow for word-at-a-time CRC calculation for both big-endian and little-
   >   endian machines, where a word is four bytes.

Comment: In short, the polynomial is 0x104C11DB7. It does implement the ANSI X3.66 CRC-32. It would be nice if the man crc32 page included this its prose.

Comment: @LukePerkins consider filing a bug report.

Comment: @muru: I would love to. Not intuitively obvious how to do this. I do not have enough "points".

Comment: @LukePerkins You don't points (not on this site, anyway). See http://askubuntu.com/a/5126/158442, essentially: run `ubuntu-bug libarchive-zip-perl`.

Comment: @muru: Thank-you. That works. Done